# Checking if remote/external webpage is available and get status code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know there's been plenty of questions and answers about checking whether a remote webpage is available, using System.Net.WebRequest, but I haven't found the methods 100% useful for my situation.

I need to check if a page is available, doesn't return a 404 or 500 error, and if there are redirects then I want to follow them until a working page is found. If the remote page requires authentication (401 unauthorised) I want to know as this may be acceptable in some cases.

When a request is made and the remote server returns an internal server error (500) WebRequest raises an exception.

I have also found that 301 redirects also raise an exception although in my situation I would like to check if the redirect is to a valid page.

Is there any other method of checking whether a page exists and preferably getting the actual HTTP status code or an exception only if there is an error getting headers (ie. invalid domain name, etc)?

This is how I'm doing it now which isn't good enough...

```
protected bool URLExists(string url)
{
    bool result = false;

    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Timeout = 1200;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        //webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        //webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36";

        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            //result = true;

            int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
            if (statusCode >= 100 && statusCode < 400) //Good requests
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode <= 510) //Server Errors
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You might find this an easier problem to solve by breaking the request logic from the logic handling the response code.  Try writing a function that excepts or returns response code, then you can determine how to respond to the code you get.

Comment: With the exception I get for one particular webpage I don't seem to be able to determine that it was 301, which is what the headers actually say if I look in Firefox Live HTTP headers tool.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not good enough'?

Comment: Are you open to use a nuget package ? Or you really want it to work with `WebRequest` ?

Comment: @rhughes, essentially what I want to check for is that the requested URL takes you to a valid page. If redirects happen along the way that's ok. If a page needs authentication (401) then there's no way of checking so it is assumed to be okay. If there's a 404 or 500 then definitely not a valid page. But my current solution doesn't handle these requirements, eg. some redirects result in an exceptions.

Comment: @Chris, ideally would prefer to use something within the framework

Comment: What are those pages where you get exception from 301 redirect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about this code, you need to get 200 response status code to sure the webpage is available, if redirects happend follow for the end point URL response status code.

```
public static bool URLExists(string url)
        {
            HttpStatusCode result = default(HttpStatusCode);

            var request =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            try
            {
                using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
                {
                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                            return true;
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
                        {
                            string uriString = response.Headers["Location"];
                            return URLExists(uriString);
                        }

                        response.Close();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                using (WebResponse response = e.Response)
                {
                    HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error code: {0}", httpResponse.StatusCode);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

is well enough? ;)

Comment: i have no idea "is well enough", but i do know that an answer of ONLY *uncommented* code is bad form. Yes I know we should all "think about it" but maybe you could elaborate a bit.

Comment: @Damirchi, this shows some promise. I didn't realise the status code was available in the exception. Might need a bit of work to handle redirects but it could work. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @Damirchi, need to change the line `string uriString = request.Headers["Location"];` from request to response.

Comment: Personal preference but I would move the recursion `return URLExists(uriString);` out of `using` block so that if there are a fair number of redirects you are not leaving open those resources any longer than necessary.

Comment: Note that this code does not protect from infinite redirects. Maybe you saw "too many redirects" error in some browsers - in this case this code will bring down whole process with stack overflow. Also, not just HttpStatusCode.Redirect (302) indicates redirect. There are also MovedPermanently and so on (basically all 3xx family).

Comment: I have gone with this answer as it showed me how to get the status code in the exception and handles redirects. I have had to modify it so that it limits the number of redirects, moves the redirect checking out of the "using", handles all types of redirects including "relative" redirects, and also accepts status codes such as unauthorised and service unavailable.

Comment: A few more notes about using this solution: (a) some websites return a NotAcceptable status code when the HEAD method is used, so I changed to GET method; (b) some websites did not return OK status unless I agent a genuine UserAgent; (c) in addition to Redirect and MovedPermanently status codes I found some used the Found status code.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an optional parameter to accept certain status codes when necessary (like 401, 403). Also, your function is doing 2 things at the same time, I separated them into `Func<>` to illustrate but fell free to create private functions in your class or wherever fells most appropriate. And since 401 is throwing an exception, you need to extract the status code from the exception.

```
protected bool URLExists(string url, params int[] acceptableCodes)
{
    Func<string, int> getStatusCode = pageUrl =>
    {
        var statusCode = -1; // Default status code
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(pageUrl);
        webRequest.Timeout = 1200;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response = null;
        try
        {
            response = webRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            response = webException.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;

                response.Close();
            }
        }

        return statusCode;
    };

    Func<int, bool> isStatusCodeOk = code =>
    {
        if (acceptableCodes != null && acceptableCodes.Contains(code))
        {
            // Accept this code
            return true;
        }

        if (code >= 100 && code < 400) //Good requests
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (code >= 500 && code <= 510) //Server Errors
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Default
        return false;
    };

    var statusCode = getStatusCode(url);

    return isStatusCodeOk(statusCode);
}
```

And the following passes:

```
Assert.IsTrue(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/200"));
Assert.IsTrue(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/301"));
Assert.IsTrue(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/302"));

Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/400"));
Assert.IsTrue(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/401", 401, 403));
Assert.IsTrue(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/403", 401, 403));
Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/404"));

Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/500"));
Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/502"));
Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/503"));
Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://httpstat.us/504"));

Assert.IsFalse(URLExists("http://whatever.invalid"));
```

Comment: `response.Dispose();` - System.Net.HttpWebResponse does not contain a definition for dispose?

Comment: I was using .Net 4.5.2, just change it back to `.Close()`